# Summarise_at where 1 row contains only NA in R

Tags: r, aggregate

The goal is to compact a dataframe of lists.

**Reproducible example**

```
data <- data.frame(A = c(rep(111, 3), rep(222, 3)), 
                   B = c(rep(c(100), 3), rep(200,3)), 
                   C = rep(c(1,2,NA),2), 
                   D = rep(c(1,2),3), 
                   E = rep(c(NA,NA,NA),2))

data
```

> ```
>     A   B  C D  E
> 1 111 100  1 1 NA
> 2 111 100  2 2 NA
> 3 111 100 NA 1 NA
> 4 222 200  1 2 NA
> 5 222 200  2 1 NA
> 6 222 200 NA 2 NA
> ```

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

data <- data %>% 
     split(data$A)

dataNew <- lapply(data,function(x){
    x %>% 
      group_by(A, B) %>% 
      summarise_at(vars(-group_cols()), ~ str_c(.[!is.na(.)], collapse=","))})
```

> Error: Column `E` must be length 1 (a summary value), not 0

```
dataNew <- bind_rows(dataNew)
```

**Desired Output**

```
DataNew
# A tibble: 2 x 5
# Groups:   A [2]
      A     B C     D     E    
  <dbl> <dbl> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1   111   100 1,2   1,2,1  "Empty"   
2   222   200 1,2   2,1,2  "Empty"
```

The code works as expected until the case arises of the empty column.
My attempted solutions just leave me scratching my head in confusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap up the logic you need in a function, and replace `str_c` with it as a direct drop-in for the code you've already written:

```
your_str_c <- function(x, collapse = ",") {
  if (length(x) == 0) {
    "empty"
  } else {
    stringr::str_c(x, collapse = collapse)
  }
}
```

And you'll have exactly your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a way to do:

```
# groupy and paste values
data[,list(paste(C[!is.na(C)], collapse = ','), 
           paste(D[!is.na(D)], collapse = ','),
           paste("empty", paste(E[!is.na(E)], collapse = ','))),.(A,B)]

# set column names
colnames(data1) <- LETTERS[1:5]

print(data1)

     A   B  V1    V2     V3
1: 111 100 1,2 1,2,1  empty 
2: 222 200 1,2 2,1,2  empty
```

Basically, the idea is to group by and filter the respective columns for NA values.

Comment: I noticed that you are listing out all columns. Could this be adapted for applications that have many rows of varying names. Put in other terms easily adapt to different numbers of column and column names

Comment: yes, it is possible but in that case the syntax would be bit different, you would define `.SDcols` and use `lapply` to do that automatically instead of writing every column name.